# How can I remove ctl00_Body_ from ctl00_Body_grvDocs_ctl45_hypDocNav in gridview's hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I have auto ID set in asp.Net. My hyperlink's ID is way too big `ctl00_Body_grvDocs_ctl45_hypDocNav` How can I reduce the ID's length? I want to keep it auto but atleast make it a bit small.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investigate the ClientIDMode property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

If you set `ClientIDMode="Static"`, your id will match in the rendered HTML, but you have the opportunity to have hyperlinks with the same ID, which will break a lot of the features of ASP.NET PostBack.  Check the link above and choose the setting right for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, You can do it. 
The way the id is generated is all the parents are appended in the id, if you do it auto. That means your HyperLink which is `hypDocNav` is inside `ct145` which inside a `grvDocs` and so on